# Attachment_fu issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, jrubyonrails, attachment-fu

I am trying to use attachment_fu + image science on jRuby-1.5.2 and Rails 3. I have followed the attachment_fu docs. However, when I upload the form form the browser, i get an error on validate_as_attachment saying size cannot be blank. This is what the log says

size can't be blank translation missing: en.activerecord.errors.messages.inclusion

when I modify the plugin to forget size check or not add validate_as_attachment check, an entry is made in the DB table but the actual file is not transfered.

Can anyone please guide me, Also is there a Rails3 compatible plugin available.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

AttachmentFu is rather old. I don't know if it's still being maintained actively.

The alternatives that pop into mind are [Paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and [Carrierwave](http://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave). Paperclip is the older one, good, but feels a bit dated. Carrierwave feels more in sync with Rails 3 and I've been hearing a lot of great things about it.

Comment: is there a migration helper to migrate old attachment_fu data into these plugin types

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your `config/locales/en.yml` file something like

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        inclusion: "Attachment"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change your attachment_fu to be a gem,
if you haven't done it yet, add this on your Gemfile:

```
git "https://github.com/pothoven/attachment_fu.git" do
  gem 'pothoven-attachment_fu'
end
```

Because this version I'm providing the link here has the patch for making it work on rails 3 and 4.
This error you are getting happens normally when you have compatibility issues.

After updating your attachment_fu then make sure that, whenever you instantiate a new image you do something like this:

```
image = YourImageModel.new()
image.uploaded_data = image_data_here
```

If you check on the implementation, the signature has changed, that's why you should change the initializations of your image models to be like this